# Does sqlite preserve COLLATE on tables in a view?

Tags: sqlite, collation

In sqlite3 collations are defined per-column. If you `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS SELECT ...` the resulting temporary table `foo` does not inherit any custom collations from the columns in the `SELECT`.  What happens if you `CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT ...`? Does the view "table" keep column collations or lose them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sqlite3 VIEWs keep the column collation from the underlying table. Proof: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/52669/3